# Trying to add listview items from different tabs to the same list array.

Tags: android, firebase, fragment

I have a TabView with lists containing data from Firebase and +/-buttons along with each item of the list.Now I want to add items to the array list on "+" button click.But instead of updating array list it's overwriting the item on button click in list view as well as tab view.

I'm referring Firebase real-time database example for this project.(https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database).

Below is my Fragment code which is then extended by different tab fragments.

```
public abstract class MenuFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "MenuFragment";
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, MenuViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private LinearLayoutManager mManager;
    int count=1;
    public ArrayList<String> orderName = new ArrayList<>();
    public MenuFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    final Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, MenuViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post,
            MenuViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MenuViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position) {

            viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View buttonView) {

                    final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

                    orderName.add(model.name);

                }
            });
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}

public String getUid() {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}
public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);}
```

"orderName" is the arraylist to which I want add items on button click.
Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: You are saying that every time you have a single item in your list that is overridden?

Comment: Yes....on different button clicks it adds only that particular item to array list

Comment: So the ArrayList does contain only one item?

Comment: No....suppose you click 1st button of 1st tab list more than once then it'll contain that number of items but from same list entry and when you click next button then it'll reset the array list...that means again it will make very 1st entry

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not using the same instance of that list. In the first tab you have an instance and in the second you have another one. You need to add those items on the same instance of that `List`. Now, in the first tab you are adding items, and when you click again in the second tab, you instantiate the list again, which is obvious that is empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But...this is happening with same tab and different buttons also

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use same instance of the list? I am bit newbie to this. Also I had tried to use different class for list

Comment: When you are using `public ArrayList<String> orderName = new ArrayList<>();` you are creating an object of ArrayList class. So you need to add item on the same object.

Comment: Yes...that is what I'm doing

Comment: Try to move the declaration of your `public ArrayList<String> orderName = new ArrayList<>();` inside the `populateViewHolder()` method. Does it work?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...but this option is also not working...in fact it creates new array list on every new button click.

Comment: Eventually, I want to implement this [link](http://demonuts.com/2017/02/26/listview-with-button-android-studio-tutorial/) on every tab

Comment: Yes, you can give it a try.